# Select set of numbers between 2 words

Tags: regex

I have the following output:

WordA

1

2

3

4

WordB

5

6

7

8

WordC

9

10

11

12

WordA

13

14

15

16

WordB

I need to grab the numbers between the two words: WordA and WordB
I tried `(?<=WordA ).*(?= WordB)` but the problem is, it grabs ALL the numbers here, including the ones between WordC and WordA that I don't want. I only want to grab the numbers between the 2 pairs which are `1 2 3 4` and `13 14 15 16`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use this regex:

```
WordA(\s+\d+)+\s+WordB
```

this will cut you WITH WordA and WordB.
Then cut the digits with this regex:

```
\d+
```

First you will get:

> WordA
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> WordB
>
> WordA
>
> 13
>
> 14
>
> 15
>
> 16
>
> WordB

Second you will get:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 13
>
> 14
>
> 15
>
> 16

Answer (score 0):

try this: `(?<=WordA).*?(?=WordB)`.